# Как сделать замену картинок предмета при скролле, что бы создавался эффект вращения предмета

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Как можно реализовать эффект, как в этом примере https://takeboost.com/ , что бы по скроллу у элемента менялись изображения и создавался эффект вращения предмета при пролистывании страницы.
У меня получилось реализовать только с учетом условия расстояния от верха страницы и в зависимости от высоты последовательно подставлять нужный ракурс изображения, но это работает, если скроллить медленно, если сделать это быстро, то последовательные изображения не прорисовываются, а появляется только изображение, которое должно быть в этом промежутке высоты.
Может быть есть какая-то библиотека или как это можно реализовать проще всего?
Ниже код с примерной реализацией, знаю, что это можно в цикле, но так нагляднее. Спасибо

```
const 3dImage = document.querySelector(".3d-image");

const images = [
  "/images/1.png",
  "/images//2.png",
  "/images/3.png"
]

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
  var scr = $(this).scrollTop();

 if (scr == 0 && scr < 100) {
     3dImage .src = images[0];
   }
   if (scr > 100 && scr < 200) {
     3dImage .src = images[1];
   }
   if (scr > 200 && scr < 300) {
    3dImage .src = images[2];
   }
}
```

Comment: они используют библиотеку - https://greensock.com
в эту сторону и нужно копать, ну и само собой ваш товар должен тоже у вас быть пофотографирован 360 градусов

Comment: Многокадровое изображение. Альтернативой м.б. использование webgl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Вариант с canvas и картинками (✔)

За данным вариантом автор вопроса обратился лично, из-за того, что **Вариант с картинками** подлагивал в FF.
Тут по сути тоже самое, только картинка не грузит DOM, т.к. отрисовывается в `canvas`.

Так же тут добавлена переменная `imgKeyframe = [66, 128]`, т.к. у автора был набор картинок и нужно было "крутить" определённый "диапазон" картинок (с 66 по 128).

```js
let imgPath = 'https://via.placeholder.com/256.png/999/000/?text=',
        img
        can = document.querySelector('#rotate-model'),
        ctx = can.getContext('2d'),
    cW = can.width = window.innerWidth,
    cH = can.height = window.innerHeight,
    preloadIMG = [],
    imgKeyframe = [66, 128], // start, end
    imgLen = 0,
    imgCur = 0,
    step = 3;
    
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    cW = can.width = window.innerWidth;
  cH = can.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx = can.getContext('2d');
}, false);

function preload() {
    for(let i = imgKeyframe[0]; i <= imgKeyframe[1]; i++) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = imgPath+i+'.png';
    img.onload = function() {
      preloadIMG.push(img);
      if(i === imgKeyframe[1]) {
        imgLen = preloadIMG.length;
        ImgDraw();
        RotateScroll();
      }
    }
  }
} preload();

function RotateScroll() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    let a = Math.floor((window.scrollY / imgLen) * step),
        i = a >= imgLen ? a - (imgLen * Math.floor(a / imgLen)) : a;
    if(imgCur !== i) {
      ImgDraw();
      imgCur = i;
    }
  });
}

function ImgDraw() {
    let img = preloadIMG[imgCur];
  drawImageScaled(img, ctx);
}

function drawImageScaled(img, ctx) {
   var canvas = ctx.canvas ;
   var hRatio = canvas.width  / img.width    ;
   var vRatio =  canvas.height / img.height  ;
   var ratio  = Math.min ( hRatio, vRatio );
   var centerShift_x = ( canvas.width - img.width*ratio ) / 2;
   var centerShift_y = ( canvas.height - img.height*ratio ) / 2;  
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width, img.height, centerShift_x, centerShift_y, img.width*ratio, img.height*ratio);  
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 1000vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#rotate-model {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="rotate-model"></canvas>
```

---

### Вариант с 3D моделью и [Three.js](https://threejs.org/)

Для этого способа, советую произвести оптимизацию модели.
(Обратиться за это к знающим людям, они без проблем это сделают)

Суть такова, модель отрисовывается в `canvas` и каждый раз когда мы скроллим, она вращается вокруг своей оси, profit.

В качестве примера вращение куба:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, .1, 1000);

scene.background = null;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(300,300);
document.querySelector('#rotate-model').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'blue'});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 2;

function ScrollCubeRotate() {
  let scrollY = window.scrollY;
  cube.rotation.y = scrollY / 360;
}
ScrollCubeRotate();

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ScrollCubeRotate();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#rotate-model {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>

<div id="rotate-model"></div>
```

---

### Вариант с картинками

Допустим вы отрендерите 360 картинок, с каждым поворотом вашей модели (можно поэкспериментировать и сделать меньше кол-во картинок, чтобы "анимация" поворота не была "рваной" и при этом количество картинок было меньшим)
Далее делаем директорию, допустим такую

```
/rotate-object/
  /0.png
  /1.png
  ...
  /358.png
  /359.png
```

Далее в переменной `imgsLen` указываем количество картинок, т.е. `imgsLen = 360`;
После чего в `imgsPath` указываем путь до картинок, т.е. `imgsLen = '/rotate-object/'`;
И в функции `CreateImages()` меняем строку

```
el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<img src="${imgsPath}?text=${i+1}"/>`);
```

На

```
el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<img src="${imgsPath}${i}.png"/>`);
```

После этого создадутся картинки и далее заработает скрипт, который при скролле будет заменять картинки, что воссоздаст покадровую анимацию "вращения объекта".

```js
let imgsLen = 30,
    imgsPath = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150.png/999/000/',
    el = document.querySelector('#rotate-model'),
    imgs = false, imgsCur = 0, step = 1;

function CreatImages() {
  for(let i = 0; i < imgsLen; i++) {
    el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<img src="${imgsPath}?text=${i+1}"/>`);
  }
  imgs = el.querySelectorAll('img');
  RotateScroll();
};
CreatImages();

function RotateScroll() {
  imgs[imgsCur].style.display = 'block';
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    let a = Math.floor((window.scrollY / imgsLen) * step),
        i = a >= imgsLen ? a - (imgsLen * Math.floor(a / imgsLen)) : a;
    if(imgsCur !== i) {
      imgs[imgsCur].style.display = '';
      imgs[i].style.display = 'block';
      imgsCur = i;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#rotate-model {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}

#rotate-model > img {
  display: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate-model"></div>
```

Добавил ещё переменную `step`, для того, чтобы задавать "ускорение" анимации, в случае когда будет 360 картинок, её потребуется увеличить, ибо за высоту примера, модель не "перевернётся" вокруг своей оси.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и реализацию, отличный вариант, попробовал, все бы подошло, но моя модель будет весить слишком много, с простым кубом все проще)

Comment: @Pavel, оптимизировать модель, поработать с топологией, использовать одну развёртку (если позволяет) и думаю она будет весить столько же, сколько и куча отрендеренных фоток модели) Если не секрет, можете показать модель?

Comment: огромное спасибо, за сегодня перепробовал разные варианты, везде работало немного не так, как нужно, код который вы привели выше идеальный вариант на данный момент)оптимизировать модель сильно не получится, несколько оборотов с изменениями вписались в 300 фото, этого достаточно, возможно еще поработаю над оптимизицией и плавностью, но ваш код решил главный вопрос) спасибо, я наконец разобрался) ссылка на одно из фото модели https://a.radikal.ru/a34/2110/ff/593df1b74176.png

Comment: @Pavel, рад что мой ответ помог. Если можете, отметьте его как правильный (слева-вверху от ответа галочка). По поводу модели, она простая и её можно оптимизировать и вставить как модель, сильно много она весить не будет, точно меньше ваших картинок (82.5кб одна фотка, если 300, то выходит почти 30мб, модель можно оптимизировать и они точно будет весить меньше раз в 6 точно).

Comment: Пометил ответ правильным, спасибо) по ссылке я скинул png, в проекте использовал webp, они получаются в 2 раза легче. Сложность в модели - там меняется цвет подсветки, по этому изображения в данной ситуации предпочтительнее, но при возможности попробую использовать модель и three.js, это удобнее при возможности)